# Persisting file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file, persistence

I have got a **file** (e.g. "file.ieee") that comes **embedded** in my **App** (included in Assets at build time).

The app will fetch a new version from a web-service and store it locally in a temporary directory (see code below).

How do I substitute (and persist) the new version?

```
    // Construct the NSURL for the download location.
    let downloadingFilePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("downloaded-file.ieee")
```

I basically want to copy the content of **downloaded-file.ieee** in "file.ieee".

Comment: Just construct a download location using a folder thats not temporary. BTW you should read this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

[`FileManager`'s class method `copyItem(at:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1412957-copyitem)

```
do {
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: temporaryURL, to: permanentURL)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```